Debian 11 bullseye (xfce) wifi firmware
I was following this guide to upgrade from Debian 11 bullseye to Debian 12 bookworm by following the steps given in https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html. I was feeling too adventurous to take a backup.
I reached step 4.2.5 to purge obsolete packages and also performed one additional command to purge all removed packages.
I then decided to reboot the machine and realized that wifi was not detected after the reboot. Can I please get an idea of how deep in trouble I am and how to recover from this?
Thank you.
Following is the output for apt list '~o' and apt purge '~o' commands.
user@debian:~$ sudo apt list '~o'
[sudo] password for user:
Listing... Done
amd64-microcode/now 3.20191218.1 amd64 [installed,local]
atmel-firmware/now 1.3-4.1 all [installed,local]
bluez-firmware/now 1.2-4 all [installed,local]
dahdi-firmware-nonfree/now 2.11.1.0.20170917-1 all [installed,local]
firmware-amd-graphics/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-atheros/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-bnx2/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-bnx2x/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-brcm80211/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-cavium/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-intel-sound/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-intelwimax/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-ipw2x00/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-ivtv/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-iwlwifi/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-libertas/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-linux-nonfree/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-linux/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-misc-nonfree/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-myricom/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-netronome/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-netxen/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-qcom-media/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-qcom-soc/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-qlogic/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-realtek/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-samsung/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-siano/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-sof-signed/now 1.7-1 all [installed,local]
firmware-ti-connectivity/now 20210315-3 all [installed,local]
firmware-zd1211/now 1:1.5-7 all [installed,local]
intel-microcode/now 3.20220510.1~deb11u1 amd64 [installed,local]
iucode-tool/now 2.3.1-1 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-image-5.10.0-28-amd64/now 5.10.209-2 amd64 [installed,local]
midisport-firmware/now 1.2-4 all [installed,local]
user@debian:~$ sudo apt purge '~o'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  amd64-microcode* atmel-firmware* bluez-firmware* dahdi-firmware-nonfree* firmware-amd-graphics* firmware-atheros*
  firmware-bnx2* firmware-bnx2x* firmware-brcm80211* firmware-cavium* firmware-intel-sound* firmware-intelwimax*
  firmware-ipw2x00* firmware-ivtv* firmware-iwlwifi* firmware-libertas* firmware-linux* firmware-linux-nonfree*
  firmware-misc-nonfree* firmware-myricom* firmware-netronome* firmware-netxen* firmware-qcom-media*
  firmware-qcom-soc* firmware-qlogic* firmware-realtek* firmware-samsung* firmware-siano* firmware-sof-signed*
  firmware-ti-connectivity* firmware-zd1211* intel-microcode* iucode-tool* linux-image-5.10.0-28-amd64*
  midisport-firmware*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 35 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 857 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 227255 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing amd64-microcode (3.20191218.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing atmel-firmware (1.3-4.1) ...
Removing bluez-firmware (1.2-4) ...
Removing dahdi-firmware-nonfree (2.11.1.0.20170917-1) ...
Removing firmware-linux (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-linux-nonfree (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-amd-graphics (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-atheros (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-bnx2 (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-bnx2x (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-brcm80211 (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-cavium (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-intel-sound (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-intelwimax (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-ipw2x00 (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-ivtv (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-iwlwifi (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-libertas (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-misc-nonfree (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-myricom (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-netronome (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-netxen (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-qcom-media (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-qcom-soc (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-qlogic (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-realtek (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-samsung (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-siano (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-sof-signed (1.7-1) ...
Removing firmware-ti-connectivity (20210315-3) ...
Removing firmware-zd1211 (1:1.5-7) ...
Removing intel-microcode (3.20220510.1~deb11u1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing iucode-tool (2.3.1-1) ...
Removing linux-image-5.10.0-28-amd64 (5.10.209-2) ...
E: Aborting removal of the running kernel
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.10.0-28-amd64 (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.10.0-28-amd64 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.10.0-28-amd64
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

and output for apt list '~c' and apt purge '~c'
user@debian:~$ sudo apt list '~c'
Listing... Done
amd64-microcode/now 3.20191218.1 amd64 [residual-config]
atmel-firmware/now 1.3-4.1 all [residual-config]
cracklib-runtime/oldstable,now 2.9.6-3.4 amd64 [residual-config]
cryptsetup-initramfs/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 2:2.3.7-1+deb11u1 all [residual-config]
cryptsetup/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 2:2.3.7-1+deb11u1 amd64 [residual-config]
dahdi-firmware-nonfree/now 2.11.1.0.20170917-1 all [residual-config]
firmware-ipw2x00/now 20210315-3 all [residual-config]
firmware-ivtv/now 20210315-3 all [residual-config]
goaccess/oldstable 1:1.4-1 amd64 [residual-config]
intel-microcode/now 3.20220510.1~deb11u1 amd64 [residual-config]
kded5/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 amd64 [residual-config]
keyutils/oldstable,now 1.6.1-2 amd64 [residual-config]
kio/oldstable,now 5.78.0-5 amd64 [residual-config]
kwayland-data/oldstable,now 4:5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
kwayland-integration/oldstable,now 5.20.5-1 amd64 [residual-config]
libkf5archive5/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 amd64 [residual-config]
libkf5attica5/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 amd64 [residual-config]
libkf5auth-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5codecs-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5configwidgets-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5coreaddons-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-4 all [residual-config]
libkf5crash5/oldstable,now 5.78.0-3 amd64 [residual-config]
libkf5dbusaddons-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5globalaccel5/oldstable,now 5.78.0-3 amd64 [residual-config]
libkf5iconthemes-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5idletime5/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 amd64 [residual-config]
libkf5jobwidgets-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5kiocore5/oldstable,now 5.78.0-5 amd64 [residual-config]
libkf5notifications-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5notifications5/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 amd64 [residual-config]
libkf5package-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-3 all [residual-config]
libkf5service-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5solid5/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 amd64 [residual-config]
libkf5sonnet5-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5wallet-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5windowsystem-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5xmlgui-data/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 all [residual-config]
libkf5xmlgui5/oldstable,now 5.78.0-2 amd64 [residual-config]
libpwquality-common/oldstable,now 1.4.4-1 all [residual-config]
linux-image-5.10.0-23-amd64/now 5.10.179-3 amd64 [residual-config]
linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64/oldstable-security,now 5.10.191-1 amd64 [residual-config]
linux-image-5.10.0-26-amd64/now 5.10.197-1 amd64 [residual-config]
linux-image-5.10.0-27-amd64/oldstable-security,now 5.10.205-2 amd64 [residual-config]
linux-image-5.10.0-29-amd64/oldstable-security,now 5.10.216-1 amd64 [residual-config]
linux-image-5.10.0-30-amd64/oldstable,oldstable-security,now 5.10.218-1 amd64 [residual-config]
linux-image-5.10.0-31-amd64/oldstable-security,now 5.10.221-1 amd64 [residual-config]
live-tools/oldstable,now 1:20190831 all [residual-config]
phonon4qt5/oldstable,now 4:4.11.1-4 amd64 [residual-config]
user-setup/oldstable,now 1.88 all [residual-config]
user@debian:~$ sudo apt purge '~c'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  amd64-microcode* atmel-firmware* cracklib-runtime* cryptsetup* cryptsetup-initramfs* dahdi-firmware-nonfree* firmware-ipw2x00* firmware-ivtv* goaccess* intel-microcode* kded5* keyutils* kio* kwayland-data*
  kwayland-integration* libkf5archive5* libkf5attica5* libkf5auth-data* libkf5codecs-data* libkf5configwidgets-data* libkf5coreaddons-data* libkf5crash5* libkf5dbusaddons-data* libkf5globalaccel5*
  libkf5iconthemes-data* libkf5idletime5* libkf5jobwidgets-data* libkf5kiocore5* libkf5notifications-data* libkf5notifications5* libkf5package-data* libkf5service-data* libkf5solid5* libkf5sonnet5-data*
  libkf5wallet-data* libkf5windowsystem-data* libkf5xmlgui-data* libkf5xmlgui5* libpwquality-common* linux-image-5.10.0-23-amd64* linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64* linux-image-5.10.0-26-amd64*
  linux-image-5.10.0-27-amd64* linux-image-5.10.0-29-amd64* linux-image-5.10.0-30-amd64* linux-image-5.10.0-31-amd64* live-tools* phonon4qt5* user-setup*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 49 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-33-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8402-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_33.0.4.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_35.2.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_35.2.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cnl_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_dmc_ver1_09.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_08.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/rkl_dmc_ver2_02.bin for module i915
(Reading database ... 224497 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for libkf5codecs-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libpwquality-common (1.4.4-1) ...
Purging configuration files for atmel-firmware (1.3-4.1) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5package-data (5.78.0-3) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5idletime5:amd64 (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5service-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.10.0-26-amd64 (5.10.197-1) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5notifications5:amd64 (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for cryptsetup (2:2.3.7-1+deb11u1) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5auth-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for intel-microcode (3.20220510.1~deb11u1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.10.0-23-amd64 (5.10.179-3) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5archive5:amd64 (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5windowsystem-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for kded5 (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.10.0-30-amd64 (5.10.218-1) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5xmlgui-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5xmlgui5:amd64 (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5configwidgets-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for amd64-microcode (3.20191218.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.10.0-29-amd64 (5.10.216-1) ...
Purging configuration files for goaccess (1:1.7.2-bullseye) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5coreaddons-data (5.78.0-4) ...
Purging configuration files for cracklib-runtime (2.9.6-3.4) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.10.0-27-amd64 (5.10.205-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5globalaccel5:amd64 (5.78.0-3) ...
Purging configuration files for dahdi-firmware-nonfree (2.11.1.0.20170917-1) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.10.0-31-amd64 (5.10.221-1) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5kiocore5:amd64 (5.78.0-5) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5dbusaddons-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5notifications-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5crash5:amd64 (5.78.0-3) ...
Purging configuration files for firmware-ipw2x00 (20210315-3) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5wallet-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5jobwidgets-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for kio (5.78.0-5) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5sonnet5-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5iconthemes-data (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for phonon4qt5:amd64 (4:4.11.1-4) ...
Purging configuration files for live-tools (1:20190831) ...
Purging configuration files for keyutils (1.6.1-2) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64 (5.10.191-1) ...
Purging configuration files for user-setup (1.88) ...
Purging configuration files for cryptsetup-initramfs (2:2.3.7-1+deb11u1) ...
Purging configuration files for kwayland-data (4:5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for firmware-ivtv (20210315-3) ...
Purging configuration files for kwayland-integration:amd64 (5.20.5-1) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5attica5:amd64 (5.78.0-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libkf5solid5:amd64 (5.78.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-33-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8402-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_33.0.4.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_35.2.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_35.2.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cnl_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_dmc_ver1_09.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_08.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/rkl_dmc_ver2_02.bin for module i915

Then I did the following to reboot:
user@debian:~$ sudo reboot
Connection to debian closed by remote host.
Connection to debian closed.


With the upgrade from Debian 11 "bullseye" to Debian 12 "bookworm", the non-free firmware packages were moved from the section non-free to the section  non-free-firmware, in response to this vote. This means that in order to keep non-free packages on your system, you need to add the non-free-firmware section to your sources.list file; e.g., something like this:

deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

If you were previously only using contrib and/or non-free for the firmware files that are found there, then you can simplify:

deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main non-free-firmware

as there are very few packages in non-free-firmware that require contrib.
After that, provided you have an alternative network link, you should be able to reinstall the non-free firmware packages again. If you don't have an alternative network link, you may need to use --print-uris:

apt-get --print-uris install firmware-*

This should show you all the URLs of the packages to download, which you can copy (using a USB stick or some such) to another machine, where you can then download the packages, write them to the same USB stick, plug them in the original machine again, and then install them like this:

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

(which is, incidentally, what apt does behind the scenes)

Purging obsolete packages is supposed to happen before the sources are changed, so the change in sections shouldn’t have caused a problem. The section change itself is detailed in section 4.2.8, after section 4.2.5. (I suspect however that the OP did change the repository configuration before cleaning packages…)

Hello, @Wouter Verhelst and @Stephen Kitt, thank you for your participation in solving this. I was able to undo my actions by connecting to the ethernet and running apt install to get all deleted packages back. Wifi started working again and even connected to the previously saved network. Appreciate your help.

Strangely, I did not have contrib and non-free in my sources and don't remember how these packages were installed when I setup the machine about 3 years ago. So, as the answer suggested, I had to add these before apt install

Ah, that explains it! I suspect you also didn’t reboot after step 4.2.2, which would have avoided the attempt to remove the running kernel (but the upgrade guide doesn’t mention that).

Thanks a ton for your help and this solved it, for others this is what I did as the root user.  I edited this file /etc/apt/sources.list and replaced this line deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main with this line deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware after I ran apt-get --print-uris install firmware-* I then ran apt install firmware-* then hit Y to install this installed various firmware for me.  I had to hit OK on one or two screens for the installs to complete, at around 96% it hung for a bit but finally finished.
